# Finding roots of sine variants

Tags: trigonometry, roots

Is there a way to find a function that produces all the roots of a sine variant? I have the following function:

$5e^{-.2x} \left(-\frac{1}{5}\sin x + \cos x\right)$

Because $e^x$ is monotonic I only need to find roots of the second factor. I can find *one* root of it like this:

\begin{alignat*}{3}
  & & 0 ~=~ & -\frac{1}{5}\sin x + \cos x \\
  & \implies   & - \cos x ~=~ &-\frac{1}{5}\sin x \\
  & \implies   & \cos x ~=~ &\frac{1}{5}\sin x \\
  & \implies   & 5\cos x ~=~ &\sin x \\
  & \implies   & 5~=~ &\frac{\sin x}{\cos x} \\
  & & ~=~ &\tan(x) \\
  & \implies & \tan^{-1}(5) ~=~ &x \\
\end{alignat*}

But how can I infer a formula from this that gives me any other root?

Comment: $+ \pi ~ n , n \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @Moo I tried that already and I did not get $0$. You do mean $x_i = tan^{-1}(5 + \pi n)$, right?

Comment: Almost, you want $x_n = \tan^{-1}(5) + \pi ~ n, n \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @Moo Oh, ok, yea makes sense now.

Comment: It's not because $e^x$ is monotonic, but because it vanishes nowhere.